# VB.Net Excel Pivot Filter not working

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have 2 row headers already set in code:
Product and Location.

Location items in the data fields can add up to 0

I would like to be able to exclude the zero items from the filter to show fewer items in the pivot.

```
           pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("Product"), Excel.PivotField)
            With pivotField
                .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
                .Name = " Product" 'Need space in front of the name
                .LayoutBlankLine = True
            End With


            pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("Location"), Excel.PivotField)
            With pivotField
                .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
                .Name = " Location"
                .LayoutBlankLine = True
            End With
```

Thats the product and location added.

No to add the datafields:

```
            pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("Finance Tons"), Excel.PivotField)
            With pivotField
                .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
                .Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
                .NumberFormat = "### ### ### ##0.000;[Red]-### ### ### ##0.000"
                .Name = " Financed Tons"
                .Position = 1
            End With

            pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("On Hand"), Excel.PivotField)
            With pivotField
                .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
                .Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
                .NumberFormat = "### ### ### ##0.000;[Red]-### ### ### ##0.000"
                .Name = " Stock On Hand"
                .Position = 2
            End With
```

And now add the data item to piece the 2 data fields together

```
            pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("Data"), Excel.PivotField)
            pivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
            pivotField.Name = "  "
```

The pivot is now in place

The sum of the tonnage in each location could be zero.

SO I would like to add a filter to exclude them on Location (a value filter)
value not equal to 0

This is the code I add to try that

```
            pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields(" Location"), Excel.PivotField)
            pivotField.PivotFilters.Add(Type:=Excel.XlPivotFilterType.xlValueDoesNotEqual, Value1:=0, DataField:=pivotTbl.PivotFields(" Stock On Hand"))
```

I am attempting to add the value filter on the Location field, with my " Stock on Hand" as my data field,

This keeps breaking here saying the following:
  Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Please could someone assist with this, have been battling for days now.

Comment: Have you checked if any of the totals = Null? not sure what data you are working with but if its information from a database one of the values could be null. iv only encountered this problem when iv hit strings in databases and i have tried to put them into a pivot.

Comment: also this problem occurs if you are using a backwards compatible sheet (a .xls) instead of a .xlsx

To allow sheets to be opened in pre office 2007 version it can't contain more than 65k rows. You can check the number of rows in your sheet by using ctrl+arrowdown till you hit the bottom. If you try to get a range larger than that number of rows it will create an error.

Comment: @DannyJames Im using only about 800 lines to test with before it goes into production, and no nulls, the data is all technically "perfect" data to test with. Will give the xlsx sheet a go and see what that does

Comment: In VBA, the macro recorder uses an .Add2 method. Could it be as simple as changing .Add to .Add2?

Comment: @DannyJames only had a look again now, I see it is already a .xlsx file. In excel if I pivot the data, I can immediately pivot the zero's out when value filtering on Location field, but just can't get it done in code...

Comment: @jeffreyweir I tried the Add2 function, it is unfortunately not a member of the pivotfilters and errors out.

Comment: `value1:="0"` try that, also you do know you have a space here:- `DataField:=pivotTbl.PivotFields(" Stock On Hand"))` in the string is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the "0" and also I renamed my datafield to " Stock On Hand" in order to change it's default name from "Sum of Stock On Hand" - If  I don't rename it and use comment the name change out and use "On Hand", still gives me the exact same error. Reduced my data down to around 50 lines to ensure it's not a data issue.  I can create the pivot on the data in excel and immediately the value filter is available for filtering. But if I create the pivot in code and open without the filtering - the value filter is greyed out...

Comment: Crossposted at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/106ca93a-2d15-4c26-8ac4-55c8a120044a/trying-to-add-pivot-filter-in-vbnet-and-cant-get-it-right?forum=vsto

Comment: @killua i meant the space at the beginning, and also space at the beginning here:- `pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields(" Location"), Excel.PivotField)` even though you have used `pivotField = CType(pivotTbl.PivotFields("Location"), Excel.PivotField)` just rather random to put spaces in front of strings...

Comment: The spaces have to be there if you wish to override its name on the pivot itself, and because I changed its "name" property, to read it I had to cast it by name, originally had it without any space, but could only get it accessed if I called it by name.

Comment: Most peculiar, im at a loss at this point, il have a think and comment if i have anything else that may work, apologies that i didnt help you this time :(

Comment: Thanks anyway!  I have managed to bypass this all now using Devexpress Extra Spreadsheet and running the same code through there, and exporting to xlsx and directly opening in Excel - Works 100%. But that still doesnt solve the fact I can't get it to work in Excel natively.